# Парсинг XML документа

Tags: c#

Получаю xml файл следующего содержания

```
string resp = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<response list=\"true\">\n <uid>182194</uid>\n <uid>2283152</uid>\n <uid>5637297</uid>....
```

Необходимо достать все uid использую следующий код на С#

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(resp);
var points = doc.Descendants("response");
foreach (XElement curent in points)
{
    string a = curent.Element("uid").Value;
    pad.WriteLine("id" + a);
}
```

Но удается достать всего один uid, после этого он выходи из цыкла.

Answer (score 1):

> var points = doc.Descendants("response");

этим действием вы получаете всего один элемент `<response...>` на что цикл закономерно выполняется всего один раз.

Решение достаточно простое:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(resp);
var points = doc.Descendants("uid");
foreach (XElement curent in points)
{
    string a = curent.Value;
    Console.WriteLine("id" + a);
}
```